# Table for HANA XSJOBS

Tags: hana

I am looking for a table in HANA where I can find the XSJOB details such as when was it last run, its status etc. TBTCO is used generally in SAP, but not sure if that's the right table in HANA too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSJOB service uses tables in the `_SYS_XS` schema:

```
select * from _SYS_XS.JOBS;

/*
NAME                                                        DESCRIPTION                             ACTION                                                                                      USER    LOCALE  STATUS      START_TIME  END_TIME    SESSION_TIMEOUT SIGNATURE_VERSION   ACTIVATED_BY    ACTIVATED_AT    CONFIGURED_BY   CONFIGURED_AT               SCHEMA_NAME
Scheduled_Backup::DataBackup                                Create data backup of database S20      BACKUP_SCHEDULER_BACKUP_DATA_DEV                                                            ?       ?       INACTIVE    ?           ?           0               0                   ?               ?               SYSTEM          23/10/2018 1:09:58.915 AM   ?          
Scheduled_Backup_Retention::DeleteBackups                   Delete backups of database S20          BACKUP_RETENTION_DELETE_BACKUPS_DEV                                                         ?       ?       INACTIVE    ?           ?           0               0                   ?               ?               SYSTEM          23/10/2018 1:09:58.95 AM    ?          
sap.hana.xs.admin.webdispatcher.server.jobs::httpTracing    Enable HTTP Tracing                     sap.hana.xs.admin.webdispatcher.server.jobs:callTracingProcedure.xsjs::callTracingProcedure ?       ?       INACTIVE    ?           ?           0               0                   ?               ?               ?               ?                           ?          
sap.hana.xs.admin.jobs.server.common::cleanJobLog           Sweep old entries from _SYS_XS.JOB_LOG  sap.hana.xs.admin.jobs.server.common:cleanJobLog.xsjs::clean                                ?       ?       INACTIVE    ?           ?           0               0                   ?               ?               ?               ?                           ?          
*/

select * from _SYS_XS.JOB_SCHEDULES;

/*
ID  JOB_NAME                                                    XSCRON          DESCRIPTION                                                             PARAMETER                                                               ORIGIN      STATUS  CHANGED_BY  CHANGED_AT
7   sap.hana.xs.admin.webdispatcher.server.jobs::httpTracing    * * * * 23 59 * SAP Web Dispatcher HTTP Tracing Job                                     ?                                                                       DESIGNTIME  ACTIVE  ?           ?         
8   sap.hana.xs.admin.jobs.server.common::cleanJobLog           * * * * 0 0 0   Clean up schedule for sap.hana.xs.admin.jobs.server.common::cleanJobLog {"day":1,"jobName":"sap.hana.xs.admin.jobs.server.common::cleanJobLog"} DESIGNTIME  ACTIVE  ?           ?         
*/

select * from _SYS_XS.JOB_LOG;

/* no example for this - check your own system*/
```